# Why do companies ask for Permanent Address?

Tags: united-states, applications

I've seen in multiple applications, companies ask for Permanent Address.

Afaik, if at all, they should only be concerned about Mailing Address. Even that is not necessary in the world of emails. 
Why, then, do companies ask for these details?

Let me clarify: I'm asking why this information is being asked in the application, rather than after they've decided to hire me. Also, this is not company-specific. Many, many companies have this in their application form (at least 10 of my 22 applications).

Comment: Are you located in the US ?

Comment: Yes @Job_September_2020

Comment: Did you try asking the HR/Admin department the same question? There's no harm - they might be able to provide a much better (and accuracte) answer.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Its not company-specific. Many, many companies have this in their application forms

Comment: @whoisit: they are legally required to ask. Your place of residence has significant impact on what tax laws apply to you.

Answer (score 4):

In some states, having an employee working in that state (even remotely) means that the company has to register with the state using an "agent" in that state, file unemployment taxes in that state, and perhaps pay corporate taxes to that state on the corporate income. The company may also need to withhold state income taxes for that state from your income. If you are in a state where the company does not have a presence already and they don't want to have that overhead, they will not hire you. Thus, they need to know which state you reside in.

Answer (score 2):

Emails are nice, fast, and convenient. But, there are a few things that require your official permanent address, or mailing address.

Some of them are:

1. **Income Tax**: Your company will provide your permanent address to the IRS (the tax agency in the US). **The IRS won't contact anyone via emails**. The IRS will mail your income tax info to your permanent
   address via paper mails.
2. **Official contact info**: your permanent address will be used for this
   purpose. They will use this permanent address for your health insurance policy, life insurance policy, 401K, etc...
3. **Remote, Onsite, or Hybrid Work Policy**: Some companies need to know your permanent address as they will
   decide whether to let you work onsite, remotely, or hybrid. At some
   point in the future, they may ask remote workers to work onsite. In this
   case, it will be easier if your permanent address is in the same
   city or close to the city where these companies are located.

---

For most people, their mailing address is also their permanent address.

You can talk to Human Resources at your company if you want to use a mailing address that is different from your permanent address.

Comment: Your permanent address also specifies what if any state/local taxes they have to pay on your behalf, and what insurance plans you're offered.

Comment: Also right to work if you might be in a different country